# NHibernate Session access thru multiple threads

Tags: nhibernate

I am writing an application and I finally have it saving to the database correctly.  However, I have a few problems and was wandering if someone could help point me in the right direction.

During my application load I fire off an NHibernate initialization thread that initializes NHibernate and then fires off 3 separate threads to load 3 of my objects, in order to split up and optimize the load time.

I was originally creating a temporary session in each of these threads in order to query the objects from the database; however, I was running into problems accessing one of the collections of my object saying that a session is not open or it has been closed.  I have a static session that is globally accessible throughout my Windows application and when it was calling the GetEnumerator for the collection the state of this session was still open.

I believe it has to do with the fact that the Intersection, the class in question, was loaded from a different session in the thread during the init process.  Loading all the objects form the same session works fine; however, I do run into exceptions from time to time with errors regarding sessions being used in a non thread safe manner.

My question then is this.  Is there a way to "merge" sessions onto my global session?  What can I do to set the Intersection class to where it has an open session in order to load the collection?  Is the problem that I need to open the session of the static global program session in the main thread?  Or am I going to be unable to thread the loading of the 3 different classes during my init process into 3 separate threads?

Comment: Last time I checked, NHibernate sessions were not thread safe.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that.  Is there any way to merge a session with another so thread A is aware of objects loaded in a session from thread B?  Otherwise, is there a way to fix my collection access in that one object?

Comment: You can "merge" an object loaded from one session into another. I'm not so sure about a whole session.

Comment: How do you go about accomplishing this?

Comment: You use the ISession's Merge() method to move an object into a session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can associate the object-graphs loaded with the other sessions with you main-session.

- If the objects may have changed then `MainSession.Merge(obj)` because it will load the Db-State to know what changed.
- If the objects haven't changed then `MainSession.Lock(obj, LockMode.None)` is enough to associate it with the main-session.

After that you you can use the objects as if they were loaded with your main session